# AngularJS's $htttp not passing form data into the POST request like jQuery's $ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a problem converting jQuery's `$.ajax` requests to Angularjs's `$http` requests (Angularjs v1.8.x).

I have **a form with one text input and one image/file input** an I am sending requests via form's submit button with `ng-click="uploadImage($e)"`.

I think the problem lies in Angularjs not sending filled form data together with the request.
My `$.ajax` requests are working fine, but for my `$http` requests, there are no `Form Data` inside browser's Developer Console - see the screenshots below. Responses to my `$http` requests are `200`, but returned data is not correct because form data is never sent with the request.

For both `$.ajax` and `$http` I prepare **form data** with this function:

```
    /**
     * @var form is an HTML element
     */
    function prepData(form) {
        var fdata = new FormData();
        for(var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
            var NN = form[i].nodeName.toUpperCase();

            var name = form[i].name;

            if(typeof name != "undefined" && name != "") {
                if(NN == "INPUT") {
                    var NT =  form[i].type.toUpperCase();
                    if(NT == "FILE") {
                        for(var j = 0; j < form[i].files.length; j++) {
                            fdata.append(name, form[i].files[j], form[i].files[j].name);
                        }
                    } else if(NT == "CHECKBOX" || NT == "RADIO") {
                        if(form[i].checked == true) {
                            fdata.append(name, form[i].value);
                        }
                    } else {
                        fdata.append(name, form[i].value);
                    }
                } else {
                    fdata.append(name, form[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
        return fdata;
    }
```

**`$.ajax` request options:**

```
var ajaxOptions = {
    type : "POST",
    async : true,
    url : getFullUrl(),
    data : prepData(form),
    dataType : self.dataType,
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("translate", User.settings.lang);
        request.setRequestHeader("userid", User.logged);
    }
};
```

**`$http` request options:**

```
var httpOptions = {
    type : "POST",
    async : true,
    url : getFullUrl(),
    data : prepData(form),
    dataType : self.dataType,
    headers : {
        "translate": User.settings.lang,
        "userid": User.logged,
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Content-Type": undefined,
        "transformRequest": []
    },
    eventHandlers: { 
        "readystatechange": function(event) {
            this.xhr = event.currentTarget;
        }
    }
};
```

When I compare `$.ajax` and `$http` in browser's developer tools I can see that their response-headers are identical, but request-headers differs in these properties (see the screenshots below):

- `Accept`
- `Content-Type`

**SCREENSHOT 1 - `$.ajax()`** (jQuery):
[image]

**SCREENSHOT 2 - `$http()`** (AngularJS v1.8.x):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent to $.ajax's `type: ...` is $http's `method: ...`.

In general, an `$http` request should look like this:

```
var httpOptions = {
    method : "POST",
    // ...
};

$http(httpOptions).then(function(res) { 
    // ... 
}, function(res) {
    // ...
});
```